# How to reference an object in a class using a decorator

Tags: python, django, parameterized-unit-test

I have a list of dicts defined in `setUpClass` in a `Django TestCase`:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

        myobj = MyModel.objects.create()

        cls.MY_LIST = [ 
            ({ 'key1': {'a': myobj.id, 'b': 2}},),
            ({ 'key2': {'a': myobj.id, 'b': 2}},), 
        ]
```

How do I reference `MY_LIST` using [parameterized](https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/)? E.g.

```
@parameterized.expand(MyTest().setUpClass().MYLIST):
def test_mytest(self, dict_item):
    print(dict_item.items())
```

Results in `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'MYLIST'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. In your case:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        ... # your staff
        cls.MY_LIST = [...]
        super().setUpClass()
        return cls
```

Use in tests:

```
@parameterized.expand(MyTest.setUpClass().MYLIST):
def test_mytest(self, dict_item):
    ... # your test staff
```

Don't forget, `classmethod` you can call with class. You are not need instance.

Comment: Apologies, typo in my question. It's the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're calling setUpClass to add the property MY_LIST, but setUpClass doesn't return nothing. So you can do this things:

```py
MyTest.setUpClass()
@parameterized.expand(MyTest.MYLIST):
def test_mytest(self, dict_item):
    ... # your test staff
```

or:

```py
class MyTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

        myobj = MyModel.objects.create()

        cls.MY_LIST = [ 
            ({ 'key1': {'a': myobj.id, 'b': 2}},),
            ({ 'key2': {'a': myobj.id, 'b': 2}},), 
        ]
        return cls

@parameterized.expand(MyTest().setUpClass().MYLIST):
def test_mytest(self, dict_item):
    print(dict_item.items())
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach means `setUpClass()` is called twice